# How to iterate through map in java in order to calculate difference?

Tags: java, maps, iteration

I have a `Map<Integer,Double>` that stores a key(`raceNumber`) and value(`speed`) such that:

```
race1     speed1
race2     speed2
race3     speed3
...
```

I'm currently using the `for(raceNumber : map.keySet())` method to iterate through the map, but I'm stuck because I need to calculate the difference between `speed2 - speed1`. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: where is your map that stores key and value?

Answer (score 0):

If the Race ID is a progressive ID you can use a TreeMap in order to take the order of the races.

If it's not (but you know the order) you could use a LinkedHashMap and put the data in that order.

So you can create a Race object:

```
public class Race {

    private String raceId;
    private BigDecimal speed;

    public Race(String raceId, BigDecimal speed) {
        this.raceId = raceId;
        this.speed = speed;
    }
    public String getRaceId() {
        return raceId;
    }
    public void setRaceId(String raceId) {
        this.raceId = raceId;
    }
    public BigDecimal getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }
    public void setSpeed(BigDecimal speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

}
```

Populate your map in this way:

```
    Map<String, Race> data = new TreeMap<String, Race>();

    Race race = new Race("10001", new BigDecimal(275.70));
    data.put(race.getRaceId(), race);
    race = new Race("10002", new BigDecimal(267.38));
    data.put(race.getRaceId(), race);
    race = new Race("10003", new BigDecimal(272.00));
    data.put(race.getRaceId(), race);
    race = new Race("10004", new BigDecimal(259.90));
    data.put(race.getRaceId(), race);
```

obviously you will get the data from some repository and finally calculate the speed for example in this way:

```
    List<Race> races = new ArrayList<Race>(data.values());
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < races.size(); i++) {
        Race currentRace = races.get(i);

        j = i + 1;
        if(j < races.size()) {
            Race nextRace = races.get(j);
            BigDecimal speedDiff = nextRace.getSpeed().subtract(currentRace.getSpeed());
            speedDiff = speedDiff.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
            System.out.println("Speed difference between RACE[ " + nextRace.getRaceId() + " ] and RACE[ " + currentRace.getRaceId() + " ] is: " + speedDiff);
        }
    }
```

The result will be:

```
Speed difference between RACE[ 10002 ] and RACE[ 10001 ] is: -8.32

Speed difference between RACE[ 10003 ] and RACE[ 10002 ] is: 4.62

Speed difference between RACE[ 10004 ] and RACE[ 10003 ] is: -12.10
```